# can't create new drupal 6 nodes, as another user, using drupal_execute

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to create Drupal nodes using drupal_execute and it works fine.
The only issue is that I can't add the new node as another user than the signed in user.

Seems like $form_state['values']['name'] has no effect!

Is this even possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you given the required permissions for this another user to create drupal nodes?

Comment: I have tested with different usernames that can create nodes from the drupal form. But my question still is if its even possible to create nodes as another user using drupal_execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://drupal.org/node/178506#comment-726479 - although it mentions Drupal 5.7 at first, it applies to Drupal 6 too. The gist of it is, you have to [(safely) impersonate another user](https://drupal.org/node/218104). By doing that you get access to whatever function the user has access to.

Impersonating users is as simple as

```
global $user;
$original_user = $user;
$old_state = session_save_session();
session_save_session(FALSE);
$user = user_load(array('uid' => 1));

// Take your action here where you pretend to be the user with UID = 1 (typically the admin user on a site)
// If your code fails, it's not a problem because the session will not be saved
$user = $original_user;
session_save_session($old_state);

// From here on the $user is back to normal so it's OK for the session to be saved
```

Then the action you must take is to run `drupal_execute()` with the form array you have.

Comment: kekkis you are a life saver!
I tried to overwrite the global $user before, and it worked. The problem was that the new global user was kept signed in, wich is now solved with your solution restoring the sessions.

Thank you!